# How can I populate an IList when I create a class?

Tags: c#, ilist

I have the following class:

```
public class CityViewModel
{
     public City City { get; set; }
     public IList<CityDetail> CityDetails { get; set; }

     public class CityDetail()
     {
         public CityDetail() {
         Text = new HtmlText();
         ImageFile = String.Empty;
         Correct = false;
         Explanation = new HtmlText();
     }
     public bool   Correct { get; set; }
     public HtmlText Text { get; set; }
     public string ImageFile { get; set; }
     public HtmlText Explanation { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make it so that when I do something like: `var model = new CityViewModel();`

That it creates a `CityViewModel` with ten `CityDetail` records?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to add a constructor to your CityViewModel object:

```
//Add a constructor
public CityViewModel()
{
    //Populate the variable
    CityDetails = Enumerable.Repeat(new CityDetail(), 10).ToList();
}
```